# OSError: Cannot parse file b'./models/saved_model.pb': Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.SavedModel'

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0, fastapi, onnx, oserror

I took pretrained model from github which was saved as .pth file. I used ONNX to convert model to .pb file.
Now I am trying to load same with fastAPI and I am getting error:

```
OSError: Cannot parse file b'./models/saved_model.pb': Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.SavedModel'
```

I am trying to load model with:

```
MODEL = tf.saved_model.load("./models/")
```

I also tried:

```
MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("./models/1")
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the pretrained model.

Comment: @Bhupen Here: https://github.com/xinntao/ESRGAN
But I converted this to .pb model.